# Python logger error

Tags: python, logging

Hi I am trying a sample program using `logger` in python

```
import logging
import time,sys
import os

logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('myapp1234.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.error('We have a problem')
logger.info('While this is just chatty')
logger.debug("Sample")
hdlr.flush()
time.sleep(10)
logger.error('We have a problem')
logger.info('While this is just chatty')
logger.debug("Sample")
hdlr.close()
```

This code is not dynamically printing. I tried even `handler.flush`, `sys.exit(0)`, `sys.stdout`.

When I try to open a file even by killing I am getting following error. Log is only printing after 120-200 seconds (sometimes it's taking even more).

[image]

How can I print immediately (at least by end of program)?

Did I miss any Handel closing.

Comment: From @RahulGupta. I came to know its working fine in Linux. Can any one help in windows environment..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following statement.

`time.sleep(10)`

Comment: I added sleep to verify weather its printing dynamically or know

Comment: Did the program print anything before `time.sleep()` statement was not there? Try putting a debugger and see line by line to see if a particular line keeps executing for long.

Comment: I am getting kill message only after ending 10 Seconds

Comment: I could run the same code on my linux machine with log file being generated. It seems your code is still running on your windows machine though it should have executed completely. Also, you could not open the file because your log file was still in use by your program.

Comment: are u able to tailf log file ?? But I am using windows. With python 2.7

Comment: Yes, i am able to `tailf` the log file. The log statements at the beginnning are getting printed instantly and the last 3 log statements are printing after waiting for 10s.

Comment: I am able to view in file Notepad++ by using the Document Monitor plugin  (automatically every 3 seconds).